# Trying to make a random selector with no repeats. It works, but only 4 times? (C# windows form)

Tags: c#, winforms, random

As the title says, I'm trying to make a piece of code that will randomly select a group (A-H) with no repeats in a windows form using C#. It seems to work, but after 4 times it will return that all groups have been selected. When I remove the line of code to output that they've been selected then I get an infinite loop instead. Anyone see what my issue may be?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    //these booleans are set to true if the group has already been selected
    bool A = false;
    bool B = false;
    bool C = false;
    bool D = false;
    bool E = false;
    bool F = false;
    bool G = false;
    bool H = false;

    private void selectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string selection = "error";
        while (selection == "error")
        {
            int group = RandomNumber();
            if (group == 1 && A == false)
            {
                selection = "A";
                A = true;
            }
            else if (group == 2 && B == false)
            {
                selection = "B";
                B = true;
            }
            else if (group == 3 && C == false)
            {
                selection = "C";
                C = true;
            }
            else if (group == 4 && D == false)
            {
                selection = "D";
                D = true;
            }
            else if (group == 5 && E == false)
            {
                selection = "E";
                E = true;
            }
            else if (group == 6 && F == false)
            {
                selection = "F";
                F = true;
            }
            else if (group == 7 && G == false)
            {
                selection = "G";
                G = true;
            }
            else if (group == 8 && H == false)
            {
                selection = "H";
                H = true;
            }
           else if (A == true && B == true && C == true && D == true && E == true && F == true && G == true && H == true)
          {
          selection = "all have been selected";
           }
            //else
         //   {
           //     selection = "oops";
           // };
        };
        outputRichTextBox.Text = selection; 
    }
    private int RandomNumber()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int num = rnd.Next(1, 9);
        return num;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Don't create a new Random() evry time, use a single instance of the same.

Comment: @bit you mean like Matthew suggested? I did that, but the issue persists.

Comment: There are many issues with this code. For a start, I think you mean `while (selection.Equals("error"))`

Comment: @steve Sorry, I'm a bit of a novice. I changed it to your suggestion, but nothing seems to have changed. Still get 4 random groups then "all have been selected".

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't recreate a `Random` for every use. Make it an instance or static field instead.

```
private Random rnd = new Random();

private int RandomNumber()
{
    int num = rnd.Next(1, 9);
    return num;
}
```

On top of that, you'd probably be better-off using an array to store your values. That would just make your code a bit more readable.

---

Just for the sake of making this a little easier to understand, this is what I would do.

```
public Form1()
{
    var poss = (new [] { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" })
               .OrderBy(c => RandomNumber())
               .GetEnumerator();
}

private IEnumerator<string> selections;
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void selectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selections.MoveNext())
        outputRichTextBox.Text = selections.Current;
    else
        outputRichTextBox.Text = "all have been selected";
}

private int RandomNumber()
{
    int num = rnd.Next();
    return num;
}
```

The idea here is to create and randomize the list at the beginning (through ordering by a random number), then loop through on each click until that list is empty.

Comment: I made it into a static field, but the issue persists. 4 groups chosen at random, then "all have been selected" is the next output.

Comment: @Tyler I just edited my answer to show how I would accomplish what it looks like you're going for. Is that any better? Then we can think about what might be causing problems in your original solution.

Comment: That looks a lot more efficient than my code! I tried running it and my compiler got upset about the `if (selections.MoveNext())` line though. I'm not very proficient with objects, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Is it possible to fix my original code to return more than 4 values, or is it a hopeless cause?

Answer (score 1):

First `Random` in .NET does not generate a real random number and based on the seed you pass to it's constructor, it can generate the exact series again and again. It's not a bug. It is designed so for testing your app against pseudo-random series of data, you must use `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` for generating a real random number:

```
public class SampleRandomNumber
{
    static readonly object Lock = new object();
    static readonly RNGCryptoServiceProvider Random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

    public static int NextInt32()
    {
        lock (Lock)
        {
            var bytes = new byte[4];
            Random.GetBytes(bytes);

            return BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

And `NextInt32` gives us an `int` (including even negative numbers; of-course you can just use the abs of it).